# does a larger or smaller C/W thermal resistance value indicate greater heat dissipation

Tags: resistance, thermal, heatsink

I need help understanding the heat sink thermal resistance specification. Does a larger thermal resistance value indicate it will dissipate more or less heat?

Comment: Higher thermal resistance is bad = lower thermal conduction.

Answer (score 1):

A larger thermal resistance means that for a given amount of heat dissipation the device attached to the heat sink will get hotter. So it is worse.

Be sure when comparing that all conditions are similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I also found HeatsinkUSA has a conversion chart that lists correction factors for different lengths of their heat sinks. For example a 4" length has a factor of 0.87. And their N24884 heatsink thermal resistance is C/W/3” 1.4. So 1.4 X .87 = 1.218. That also answers my question. The lower a thermal resistance number is the hotter a device it will handle.

Answer (score 0):

Heatsink thermal resistance is quoted in K/W or °C/W. For example, the temperature of a heatsink with a 10 °C/W rating will rise 10°C above ambient air for every watt it has to dissipate.

In general, larger heatsinks will have lower thermal resistance and will keep the devices cooler. Forced cooling by use of a fan can reduce the thermal resistance substantially.

[image]

*Image source: [Fischer Electronic](https://www.eenewseurope.com/news/extruded-heat-sinks-mount-directly-pcbs).*

Note that some heatsinks will assume that the power will not all come from one device attached to the heatsink but from several spaced equally along the heatsink.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does a larger thermal resistance value indicate it will dissipate more
> or less heat?*

The source of the heat is the transistor (e.g.) that is attached to the heat-sink. That heat originates from the transistor and that heat gets dissipated by the heat-sink. In the process of dissipating that heat, the heat-sink warms to a certain temperature over and above the local ambient temperature. That temperature will be higher if the thermal resistance is higher and, it will be less if the thermal resistance is lower.